# Connecting users with different authentication and permissions - mongoengine

Tags: mongodb

On my MongoDB I have 2 users – one with RW (Read Write) permission and the 
other is with RO (Read Only) permission

I'm trying to do the following:

1. connect to the same DB with different users
2. saving to DB with the different users

Expected behavior - RW user can write, RO can not write
Actual behavior - depending on connect order and save() order but

**I'm trying to use different aliases (see below) but it seems not a good strategy (also for queries) - what is the recommended method?**

my code is something like this :

```
from mongoengine import *

class rwTry(Document):
    wval = StringField()

# 1st connect
connect(alias = 'db_ro_user' ,
    db = 'myMongoDB',
    username = 'user_ro',
    password = 'user_ro_password',
    host = 'hostIP',
    port = 7382
)

# 2nd connect
connect(alias = 'db_rw_user' ,
    db = 'myMongoDB',
    username = 'user_rw',
    password = 'user_rw_password',
    host = 'hostIP',
    port = 7382
)

dbro = rwTry(wval = 'try to write')
dbro._meta['db_alias'] = 'db_ro_user'

dbrw = rwTry(wval = 'try to write')
dbrw._meta['db_alias'] = 'db_rw_user'

dbro.save() # expecting error (i get error if i do not connect to 2nd  connect above)- see below
dbrw.save()
```

in the above code - both documents are written to DB

but when i remove the 2nd connect i get as expected

```
dbro.save()
```

... Could not save document (**not authorized on myMongoDB to execute command** { insert: "rw_try", ordered: true, documents: [ { wval: "try to write", _id: 
ObjectId('57cd25f76151390cd0022bc1') } ], writeConcern: { w: 1 } })*